# WCF service only accessible when Fiddler is turned on

Tags: .net, wcf, proxy, fiddler

My client application which is on one machine is trying to access a WCF service which is on another machine.

The client application can only access the web service when Fiddler,on the client machine, is switched on. When the latter is switched off, I get the following error:

> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint
>   listening at http://ourServer.com/ProductDataServiceV1.svc that could
>   accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or
>   SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made
>   because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8888

In the hosts file I've got

> 192.168.33.55   ourServer.com

I've looked at the proxy settings in Windows explorer and all the checkboxes are turned off. I've also done a search for "127.0.0.1:8888" on the client machine but couldn't find anything of note.

Moreover, I am able to "see" the service http://ourServer.com/ProductDataServiceV1.svc in a web browser.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The text:

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8888

...almost certainly means that the client is trying to send its traffic to a Fiddler instance that isn't running. Typically, .NET applications pick up the proxy settings on startup and do not refresh them until they are restarted. So if you had Fiddler running, then started a .NET app, then closed Fiddler, you'd need to restart the .NET app.

Now, there are other possibilities as well. For instance, someone could have customized the machine.config or app.config file (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-DOTNET) or even a WebProxy object in the source code to point directly at Fiddler for troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: I've checked the source code and there is nothing pointing to 127.0.0.1:8888. I will however take your other suggestions on board and try them out. Thanks for you input.

Comment: I've now done a search for "8888" in machine.config and there was no such entry. I've then looked for the same string in the client application and again nothing was found. I'll do a restart of the client at a later point and report upon it.